# Is there a way to know which runloop or frame you are currently at?

Tags: objective-c

I am outputting debugging log and I want to know if specific methods in my code are executing in the current runloop vs. subsequent ones.  Is there a way to achieve this?

For example, a run loop in the simplest sense:

```
int i = 0;
while (1) {
  // process event queue
  // here I want to print a number 
  // that signifies n-th time I am processing the run loop
  NSLog(@"%d", i);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to query for this from inside the executing thread, or from a different thread?

Comment: Let me elaborate on my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you give each thread a name, you could query it.

```
NSThread *thread = [NSThread currentThread];
[thread name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're in the main runloop this way:

```
if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] == [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]) {
    // ...
}
```

This test will fail for any methods running on a background thread or runloop (runloops belong to threads and one exists for every thread.)

If you need to determine if a bit of code is positively running on a particular run loop, you cache the runloop reference in question in a place where you know it'll be running:

```
-(void)IKnowThisMethodRunsInASpecialRunLoop {
    _runLoopToWatch = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
} 

// ... later ...

-(void)someMethod {
    if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] == _runLoopToWatch ) {

    }
}
```